# How can I make a primefaces carousel responsive?

Tags: css, primefaces

I am currently facing a problem regarding primefaces' carousel and its responsiveness when resizing my website.

This is how it looks like when I load my website:

[image]

This is the correct size and display.

However, as soon as I resize my website, this is what it turns out to look like:

[image]

It seems like the width of the entries is not recalculated on resizing my website. However, I now want to achieve making the carousel responsive.

Is there an option to set this element to recalculate its entries size on resizing?

I couldn't find one as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap:
put this into your html page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and then

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    here your carousel code
</div>
```

Comment: And then takeva gooood look at all the other PrimeFaces components. Do they still look good? The box model of bootstrap messes things up if I remember correctly

Comment: No problem for me with bootstrap and you can use juste responsives columns.

Comment: And btw, PrimeFaces has this grid to. But I doubt either of them fixes the issue the OP has. The grid does not make the content automagically responsive. It make room (or not) for the content